# ¿Cómo escoger qué .env cargar según el subdominio en Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

#### ¿Cómo hacer para que Laravel se entere del fichero .env que yo deseo cargar?

El nombre del subdominio coincide con el fichero .env, lo cargo con Dotenv y también con la aplicación de Laravel con el método loadEnvironmentFrom.

Luego ejecuto:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Y por último al comprobar $_ENV o getenv(string) puedo ver que está bien cargado, pero... No es así, Laravel sigue apuntando al fichero .env

**bootstrap/app.php**:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $hostArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $envFile = sprintf('.%s.env', $hostArray[0]);
    $path = __DIR__.'/../';
    if (count($hostArray) > 2 && file_exists($path, $envFile)) {
        $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv($path, $envFile);
        $dotenv->load();
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
    }
}

return $app;
```

Comment: Las configuraciones del archivo `.env` digamos `.admin.env` ó `.portal.env` son distintas y en cada dominio se carga la configuración que corresponde o no se carga la configuración que corresponde.

Comment: En cada dominio se debe de cargar su .dominio.env en vez del .env

Comment: "Y por último al comprobar $_ENV o getenv(string) puedo ver que está bien cargado, pero... No es así, Laravel sigue apuntando al fichero .env" a que te refieres que está bien cargado pero laravel sigue apuntando al archivo .env

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cuando he hecho cosas similares, he tenido éxito usando el método `overload()` del Loader de DotEnv, para que sea mutable la instancia, si bien no estoy 100% seguro que sea el problema en este caso, lo propongo como primera respuesta:

```
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv($path, $envFile);
    $dotenv->overload();
```

EDICIÓN:

Después de probar el código del OP en un ambiente de preproducción y revisar la documentación de PHP, error es que está pasando dos parámetros en vez de uno en la función file_exists(), la cual solo acepta un parámetro ([ver documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php)).

Una vez corregido este error, se lee el .env correcto utilizando tanto la función `load()` como `overload()` de Dotenv.

La corrección es entonces, formar un solo string con `$path` y con `$envFile`:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $hostArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $envFile = sprintf('.%s.env', $hostArray[0]);
    $path = __DIR__.'/../';
    if (count($hostArray) > 2 && file_exists($path . $envFile)) {
        $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv($path, $envFile);
        $dotenv->load();
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Shaz, he probado tu solución y no ha tenido éxito, buscaré más información por si el problema es de Dotenv.

Comment: @Shaz debería seguir siendo `overload`, en el método `DotEnv\Loader::setEnvironmentVariable` hay un `if` que dice que si es inmutable y la variable del entorno es distinta de null, no debe hacer nada.

Comment: Déjame decirte que lo probé con ambos métodos y funcionó correctamente, sin embargo estoy de acuerdo con tu apreciación (tal y como lo propuse en la primera respuesta). Ten en cuenta que al cargarlo en app.php lo estás cargando antes de "todo".

Comment: Buena esa, yo lo estaba realizando desde otro fichero.

Comment: @Shaz No funciona, Laravel continúa buscando un fichero .env :/

Comment: Pero algo debe haber distinto en tu aplicación, yo lo probé en un dominio real, con dos subdominios existentes, todo público y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Entra en el if, compruebo en $_ENV y con getenv y tengo los valores, pero luego utiliza el .env, miraré configuración de mi aplicación, pero me extraña que haya puesta una capa que intervenga en este proceso, sé que nació en Laravel 5.2 y ahora es Laravel 5.5 el proyecto, cómo no tenga que ver por ahí.

Comment: De hecho mi prueba consistió en utilizar 3 .env distintos según el subdominio, y mostrar una variable de ambiente en una plantilla de blade, y funcionó perfectamente. Fue probado con Laravel 5.5.39, dotenv 2.4.0 y un servidor Nginx en producción

Comment: Mañana volveré a realizar las pruebas, mi aplicación no tiene configuración extra que modifique el comportamiento de los .env, uso un servidor Apache en producción también y con 2 .env distintos según el subdominio pero me coge el principal .env, lo primero qué compruebo es la conexión contra la base de datos qué le corresponde.

Answer (score 4):

Revisando la clase `Dotenv\Dotenv` en el método `load`

```
public function load()
{
    return $this->loadData();
}
....
protected function loadData($overload = false)
{
    $this->loader = new Loader($this->filePath, !$overload);

    return $this->loader->load();
}
```

Genera una instancia del objeto `Dotenv\Loader`, el cual el segundo parametro es un valor booleano que indica si el objeto loader sera [inmutable](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#immutability) (que no sobreescribira las variables ya seteadas), al hacer el llamado `load()` le decimos que no sobreescriba sobre el parametro de la misma función, y al generar el objeto `Loader` le decimos que sea inmutable, por esa razón no carga el archivo que necesitas. Debes de llamar al metodo `overload` de la misma clase `DotEnv` definido de la siguiente manera:

```
public function overload()
{
    return $this->loadData(true);
}
```

dejando tu código así

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $hostArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $envFile = sprintf('.%s.env', $hostArray[0]);
    $path = __DIR__.'/../';
    if (count($hostArray) > 2 && file_exists($path. $envFile)) {
        $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv($path, $envFile);
        $dotenv->overload();
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
    }
}

return $app;
```

Comment: ¿Qué tiene de distinto esta respuesta a la mía?

Comment: cuando publiqué, la respuesta que tu colocaste no estaba a la vista.

Comment: No funciona @HammerffallBK :/

Comment: por la coma que contiene `file_exists`, debería ser punto como comentó @shaz, pero viendo las publicaciones, no se que sea en realidad, de la misma forma lo probé y carga el archivo que yo le indique.

Comment: Solo revisar si hay código que este llamando nuevamente a `load` u `overload`. El archivo `.env` si no me equivoco lo carga el `Kernel` de http en el método `bootstrap`.